# Get object from DAL via BLL into presentation via generics

Tags: c#, generics, interface

I have a bunch of BLL objects which are directly mapped entities from the database in a model first scenario. I get theese objects from the DAL via BLL into the presentation layer via interfaces like this (from the BLL layer):

```
    public static ILanguage GetNewLanguage()
    {
        return new Language();
    }


    public static bool SaveLanguage(ILanguage language)
    {
        return DAL.Repositories.LanguageRepository.Save(language);
    }
```

And in the presentation layer I get the object simply by this call:

ILanguage language = BLL.Repository.GetNewLanguage();

Now as I have a bunch of objects, I would like to make the BLL methods generic, so I don't have to write the same code for every object.

But I am not sure how to do this. Any help is appriciated, thanks.

/Finn.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, it has been a while, sorry for that!

I succeeded in creating a generic method. Instead of this for every entity:

```
public static ILanguage GetNewLanguage()
    {
        return new Language();
    }
```

I am now using this generic method (but I think it is still a clumsy way to do this):

```
public static T CreateNew<T>(out string errmsg) where T : class
    {
        errmsg = string.Empty;

        // Loading the DAL assembly as you cannot allways be sure that it is loaded,
        // as it can be used from the GAC and thereby not accessible as a loaded assembly.
        AppDomain.CurrentDomain.Load("DAL");

        // From loaded assemblies get the DAL and get the specific class that implements 
        // the interface provided, <T>.
        // It is assumed for the time being, that only one BLL dataobject implements the interface.
        var type = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies()
            .SelectMany(s => s.GetTypes())
            .Where(p => typeof(T).IsAssignableFrom(p) && p.IsClass)
            .FirstOrDefault();

        try
        {
            // Create an instance of the class that implements the interface in question, unwrap it 
            // and send it back as the interface type.
            var s = Activator.CreateInstance("DAL", type.FullName);
            return (T)s.Unwrap();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            errmsg = ex.ToString();
            return null;
        }

    }
```

The call from presentation layer now looks like this:

```
string errmsg = string.Empty;
ILanguage language = BLL.CreateNew<ILanguage>(out errmsg);
```

I solved the apparent problem, but still not in a fancy way. I have an idea of using DI to decouple assemblies from each other, but I am not sure how to do this. Comments are very wellcome. And I'll offcourse post a solution in a new thread if I find one.

And also I will post a solution to Crud's idea of how to decouple the BLL from the DAL with a repository class, in a new thread when I have figured that out!

Cheers Finn.

Comment: The generic way has certainly its disadvantages, as it is at the least 20-30 times slower than the straight one. So it depends on performance and your personal flavour what to implement...

Answer (score 0):

Creating a repository class for each entity type could result in a lot of redundant code .Just go through the following sample code to do that with generic repository pattern.

[Here](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/getting-started-with-ef-5-using-mvc-4/implementing-the-repository-and-unit-of-work-patterns-in-an-asp-net-mvc-application)

Comment: Roger, Crud! Thanks for your view, I'll look closer into it when I have solved the actually core in the question, namely how to instatiate a class which is implementing a certain interface and then return it back. Maybe I'm on the path to DI, but meanwhile I am into AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies() and Activator.CreateInstance. I'll post a solution soon. Sorry for the late comment. Cheers...